# UIScrollView performance

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have problems with the performance

There is a ScrollView, which are added 200 Buttons:

```
IMSeatControl * control = [[IMSeatControl alloc] initWithFrame: controlRect withSeatObject: seatObject];
[control addTarget: self action: @ selector (seatButtonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_seatsContentView addSubview: control];
```

The button consists of picture and label.

Is there a good way to improve the performance?

Comment: When app is slowing down - during adding those buttons to scrollview, or while scrolling between them?

Comment: When scrolling.
I have zooming, when on screen 20 - 30 buttons - its fine ... but when on screen 100 - 200 buttons device frizez